# Check string words start from @

Tags: php, split, explode

I have a string and need to get the list of all words that start from **@**

```
$string = "Hello @bablu, This is my friend @roshan. Say hi to all. Also, I introduce 1 friend that is amit@gmail.com."
```

Now in this string, **I need to get only bablu and roshan**. Not get amit@gmail.com because amit has an email address. Now I have **explode** from **@** but **explode** method split the email address too.

```
$explode = explode('@',$string); 

print_r($explode);
```

How can I get only **@** words in PHP?

```
[
 0 => "",
 1 => "bablu",
 2 => "",
 3 => "roshan",
 4 => "amit",
 5 => "gmail.com"
]
```

My excepted answer would be :

```
[
 0 => "bablu",
 1 => "roshan"
]
```

Comment: This should not be tackled using `explode` to begin with, but with `preg_match_all` and a quite simple regular expression.

Comment: @CBroe I have used preg_match but its not working for me.

Comment: Then _show us_ what you tried, and explain your reasoning behind it.

Comment: preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $body, $matches);
        return $matches[0];

Comment: If you want to get only `@bablu` and `@roshan`, then why are you looking for stuff that has characters _before_ it? You should demand a _word boundary_ before the `@` character.

Comment: `preg_match_all('#\B@([a-z]+)#i', $string, $m); var_dump($m);`

Answer (score 1):

[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) doesn't do anything , all you need is to use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$string = "Hello @bablu, This is my friend @roshan. Say hi to all. Also, I introduce 1 friend that is amit@gmail.com.";
preg_match_all('/\B@([a-zA-Z]+)/', $string, $matches); 
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output with :

```
Array
(
  [0] => bablu
  [1] => roshan
)
```

The \B matches the empty string not at the beginning or end of a word. So you can ignore that email address.

Answer (score -5):

It can be done by this..

```
$explode = explode(' @',$string);
```

By adding space before `@`